# Show or hide checkbox based on database entry

Tags: php, mysql

I want a check-box to only appear if there is a 'Y' within the database, how would I go about that?

Here is what I came up with, I have tried many other ways too ...

```
<form name="Discount" id="COTCode" action="cart.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="COTCode" id="COTCode" onclick="this.form.submit();"
</form>
Automatic discount check
<?php

    $sql  = "SELECT COTCode FROM stock";

    if ($COTCode == 'Y') {

        echo "You can recieve discount";

    } else if ($COTCode == 'N') {

        echo "Sorry this article doesn't come with discount";

    }

?>
```

Comment: `if ($value == 'y') { show checkbox } else { do nothing }`

Comment: i'd like to say this is helpful however it does not work my friend

Answer (score 1):

First, pull something from the database:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourDBName;host=yourHost;',$username,$password);
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT COTCode FROM stock
WHERE whatever_conditions
SQL;
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$costCodes = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you'll want to loop oper your results and print the HTML as necessary.

```
foreach($costCodes as $code){
    if($code['COTCode'] === 'Y') print 'You can receive a discount.';
    else print 'Sorry, this article doesn\'t come with a discount';
}
```

If you're expecting only one result, the above changes a little. Instead of `$query->fetchAll`, you can simply use `$query->fetch`. Then the loop becomes unnecessary:

```
$costCode = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($costCode['COTCode'] === 'Y') print 'You can receive a discount.';
else print 'Sorry, this article doesn\'t come with a discount.';
```